# SOQL Lookup from custom object to Account

Tags: soql, relationships

Let's say I have Lookup between custom object and standard Account object as a master. But

```
select id, name, Account.id from MyObect__c
```

always returns an error

'Didn't understand relationship Account in field path'
I'm 100% sure that there is the field with lookup to Account in MyObject. What am I doing wrong and can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're dealing with a custom SObject, then that relationship is going to be a custom field.

Therefore, it'll be `Account__c`, and you'll need to use `Account__r.Name`<sup>1</sup> in your query. That'll be true for both lookup relationships and master-detail relationships.

The only time you can avoid using `__c` or `__r` is when you're dealing with a standard relationship (e.g. `OpportunityId` between `OpportunityLineItem` and `Opportunity`)

<sup>1: If you're just looking for the Id, there's no reason to query up the relationship hierarchy. Just query for the relationship field on your custom object (i.e. `Account__c`). If you *do* need some other piece of data on the related object, then you'll need to use `__r` to access it in the query</sup>

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quiet understand your answer. I have 2 objects - standard Account object and custom MyObject. But according to your suggestions select Account__r.name doesn't work for me as well

Comment: @pincet If your relationship is a custom field then, whatever you've called it, the API name ends in `__c`. You need to change that to `__r` when you're trying to query up from a child record to get parent record data. If that's still not enough, then you should edit your question to contain more details.

Comment: Parent is the standard Account object and I need to retrieve fields using child-to-parent query

Comment: @pincet and what is the API name of your relationship field to `Account`?

Comment: Derek, it was my bad. Now it's clear. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a custom object.

```
[SELECT name, Account__c FROM MyObect__c]
```

Like Derek said before, navigate to your object and see the api name for it and add the __c to it if you are trying to get the reference for the account.